# Am I using a closure in the following code - Understanding Closures in Swift

Tags: swift, function, closures

I'm having a hard time understanding closures when used within functions.

In the following code I created a function which gets two parameters and returns a function but since I have seen a few tutorial where they show some similar examples and they refer to them as ***"capturing constants and variables values using closures"*** but on my example I don't really see the closure.

Can I say that in the code example below `incrementer()` is the closure?

```
func incrementNumber(baseNumber:Int, increaseBy: Int) -> () -> Int {

    var baseNum = baseNumber

    func incrementer() -> Int {
        baseNum += increaseBy
        return baseNum
    }

    return incrementer
}

let increase = incrementNumber(100, increaseBy: 20)
increase()
increase()
increase()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `incrementer()` is closing over the variables `baseNum` and `increaseBy`, since both variables are in scope when the function `incrementer()` is declared.

This programmers stackexchange [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/40708/197348) explains it pretty nicely. As you can see there, the example (although in javascript) looks very similar to your code here.

Comment: First of all thank you for the clearification. As I mentioned before I'm trying to understand closures when used within functions. Now, you mentioned something that caught my attention, you said... ***incrementer() is closing over the variables baseNum and increaseBy*** what do you mean when you say `closing over`? Is that how it is called when a closure is interacting with variables? Sorry about the silly question but I need to get this right.

Comment: @fs_tigre Yes. The reason it is referred to in that way is because even when those variables go out of scope in the function where they were defined, they will still be accessible to the `incrementer()` function as it holds onto the references. This of course presumes that you choose to hold onto a reference to `incrementer()` and continue to use it elsewhere.

Comment: Cool it starting to make more sense. The other concept that I still don't get  and is bothering me, is how closures work when passed as arguments. Do you know of a good tutorial that shows how closures are used as arguments but that `don't` use the `sorted` or `map` functions as examples because I haven't had any success understanding the usage that way?

Comment: A closure is just a function, like any other - you can treat them as you would any other function passed as an argument (e.g. invoke it). Languages that have closures generally treat functions as first-class - this allows you to assign them to variables and pass them around.

Comment: There are many tutorials on closure's using other programming languages, I would suggest you look for tutorial's on the concept in general, not just on their application in swift.